# Conditionally removing authorization header in Varnish Edge-side includes (ESI)

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, edge-side-includes

I'm using varnish with Edge-side includes for endpoints for which the primary endpoint requires authorization, but the ESIs usually do not... but sometimes they do. I am handling it now by adding a header I call `Keep-Authorization` to the main *request* when I want all ESI requests to retain the Authorization headers. Then I have

```
vcl_recv {
  ...
  if (req.esi_level > 0 && !req.http.Keep-Authorization) {
    unset req.http.authorization;
  ...
  }
}
```

This works OK, but is pretty inelegant--it requires the requester to know whether to add that Keep-Authorization header. While the API is currently only used by us, that may change.

In truth, the level 0 response knows whether its ESI children will require authorization, and should be able to set a header to indicate that. If I could read it in the appropriate part of the varnish lifecycle, I could remove (or not) the authorization header appropriately before ESI's are resolved base on what I get from the level 0 response.

This seems like something I would have to do in `vcl_backend_response`, but I'm not really sure. Or if in `vcl_recv` there were something like `req_top` for the top level response (which should be available by the time ESIs are being resolved) that would also do the trick.

In short, I'd like the origin to be able to determine whether the authorization header is retained for resolution of the ESIs in its response. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as `beresp_top` unfortunately. And because client logic and backend logic are split up in VCL, there is on real way to have that information in `vcl_recv` using native VCL.

A possible solution is leveraging `vmod_var`. This is an open source Varnish module that is part of https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules.

There are currently no packages for it, so you'll have to compile it from source. Depending on the version of Varnish, you need to download the right branch.

The [`var.global_set()`](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/6.0-lts/src/vmod_var.vcc#L70) function allows you to set a global variable in `vcl_backend_response`, which you can retrieve in `vcl_recv` using [`var.global_get()`](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/6.0-lts/src/vmod_var.vcc#L72)

You could then use the following VCL code to conditionally strip off the `Authorization` header:

```
vcl 4.1;

import var;

sub vcl_recv {
    if(var.global_get(req.url + "-remove-auth") == "true" || var.global_get(req_top.url + "-remove-auth") == "true") {
        unset req.http.Authorization;
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if(beresp.http.X-Remove-Auth) {
        var.global_set(bereq.url + "-remove-auth", "true");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a creative solution, and I can see how this would work (and we already compile varnish-modules, so that is no problem), but I imagine it would be pretty hacky to track all of those variables as globals. If it involved a lot of endpoints (and we have a lot of endpoints) I wouldn't feel comfortable putting all those variables into some global in-memory space. In the likely case that no one has a better solution, I'll mark this as solved in a couple days.